# How to use strtok to delimit and get new strings

Tags: c, string, strtok

I am trying to use strtok to break up a string and to store the extracted strings into new arrays so I can use them seperately as commands or something.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{

   char test_string[50]="string to split up";
   char *sub_string;

   /* Extract first string */
   printf("%s\n", strtok(test_string, " "));

   /* Extract remaining strings   */
   while ( (sub_string=strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL)
   {
       printf("%s\n", sub_string);
   }
}
```

This prints out the string I am looking for without the spaces, but how would I go about getting each of the words saved into seperate string variables instead of just printing them? Basically I want "string" to be saved into string1[] and "to" to be saved in string2[] and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original string gets "chopped into pieces" by the `strtok` operation, so you can actually do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{

   char test_string[50]="string to split up";
   char *sub_string[50];
   int ii = -1;
   /* Extract first string */
   sub_string[++ii]=strtok(test_string, " "));
   printf("%s\n", sub_string[0]);
   /* Extract remaining strings   */
   while ( (sub_string[++ii]=strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL)
   {
       printf("%s\n", sub_string[ii]);
   }
}
```

Basically, `strtok` inserts `'\0'` at the delimiter found, and returns a pointer to the start of the token. So you don't actually need to allocate new memory to the `sub_string` elements - just to the array. I set the number of elements of the array to 50; in reality you will want to make sure that your `while` loop stops before you run out of space…

A little diagram might help:

Original string:

```
s t r i n g    t o    s p l i t    u p \0
```

After first call to `strtok`:

```
s t r i n g \0 t o    s p l i t    u p \0

^ first pointer
```

After next call:

```
s t r i n g \0 t o \0 s p l i t    u p \0

               ^ second pointer
```

After the third call:

```
s t r i n g \0 t o \0 s p l i t \0 u p \0

                      ^ third pointer
```

etc.

If you want to store the substrings in "different variables" (not sure why you don't consider `sub_string[0]` and `sub_string[1]` etc to be convenient 'different variables', but I'll leave that for another time), you *could* change the above to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{

   char test_string[50]="string to split up";
   char *string1, *string2, *string3, *string4, *string5;
   int n = 0;
   /* Extract first string */
   if(strlen(test_string)==0) return 0;

   string1=strtok(test_string, " "));
   n++;
   printf("%s\n", string1);

   while( n < 5 ) {
     string2 = strtok(NULL, " ");
     if (string2 == NULL) break; else n++;
     string3 = strtok(NULL, " ");
     if (string3 == NULL) break; else n++;
     string4 = strtok(NULL, " ");
     if (string4 == NULL) break; else n++;
     string5 = strtok(NULL, " ");
     if (string4 == NULL) break; else n++;
  }
  printf("the total number of strings found is %d\n", n);
}
```

I just don't think it is nearly as elegant as using an array of `char *`. Can you see my point?

Comment: Thanks @Floris. This really cleared up my understanding of how strtok actually works. I however editted my question regarding how to save each part of the string into several string variables, I was a bit unclear about my problem.  <br\>However I have a question regarding your code. You declared ii=-1, when it is first called as ++ii, its value would have changed to 0 at that point in the code, however when the ++ii is called within the while loop, shouldn't its value be 1 this time it is called?  <br\>P.S: How do I highlight the functions i write in the comment section?

Comment: @ArmanIqbal - no problem. To highlight code in comments, surround with backticks: `\`code\``. I start with `ii=-1;` so that it will be `0` when I first increment it (for the first element in the string array); then I keep incrementing, so I can use it (after the increment) for printing it out. I will address your other question in an update to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{

   char test_string[50]="string to split up";
   char *sub_string;
   char withoutspace[50];

   /* Extract first string */
   printf("%s\n", strtok(test_string, " "));

   /* Extract remaining strings   */
   while ( (sub_string=strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL)
   {
       strcat(withoutspace, sub_string); //printf("%s\n", sub_string);
   }
}
```